# Does using inequality (<>) or NOT in where clause lead to SQL ignoring the index?

Tags: sql-server, index, where

I found this article that talks about avoiding using <> operator in where clause because optimizer ignores the index.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3203/avoid-using-not-equal-in-where-clause/

Is this absolutely true?

What is the best way to handle this? How to avoid using <> ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A `<> X` predicate *is* sargable.

SQL Server can convert it to two range seeks (on `< X` or `> X`).

Unless the index is covering for the query however you may well not see this. The tipping point for a query using a non covering index and look ups is typically very low. (at most selectivity of a single digit percent).

So unless, say, 99% of the table *does* have value `X` the `<>` will match too many rows for that plan to be chosen.

Even in this case likely you should be considering a filtered index only containing the 1% of rows that don't match `X` rather than a full index including the highly unselective value.

Unless the domain of possible values is entirely fixed and quite small you don't really have a choice between using `<> X` or writing it as `IN(all,values,that,are,not_x)` - you need to choose the one with the correct semantics for all possible values.